# Ember: Advanced D&D Interface Concept - how to add components or childviews based on dropped item

Tags: ember.js, drag-and-drop, collectionview, container-view

I'm currently developing an Ember App for combining magnetic ornaments ( pls. see screenshot link ).

http://s7.postimg.org/9k2nq75yj/question_edit.png

On the left the user selects a category and then has the ability to chose main parts ( the long necklaces you see in the subcategory "Unsere Halsketten" & "Unsere Armbänder" ) or smaller parts, called elements ("Unsere Elemente") which then can be dropped into the "Drop Area".

In this early stage of development the drop area is simply a ember component which displays the content of an array (template: each item in array) . When a user drops an item to the drop area it's id is transfered through dataTransfer and a controller action (called from the component )fetches the item from the store and pushes it to the array.

As the necklaces have 2 open connections to add another item ( the items have magnetic connections) the goal now is to have a dynamic drop zone.

I'll explain:

The user drops a necklace (e.g. "ART_HALS_1") to the drop area.
As it is a part with 2 open connectors and it is a necklace (it is big) i now want it to appear in drop center. Now that there's 2 open connections i need the drop center to have 2 additional drop areas added ( drop-left & drop-right) on top of it so there can be another item attached to it (like elements "Unsere Elemente").

As this is my first ember project I'm not really sure how i should continue from here.

I started reading into containerView and collectionView but i cannot figure out a good concept.

If anybody could help me giving a path in which direction i should go, i would be very thankful for that!

Following the most important code parts.
The App is written with the help of ember-app-kit, coffescript (translated javascript version below) and for the template emblem (compiles to handlebars).
The items come from a simple rails api.

## item Model

```
App.Item = DS.Model.extend
  itemName: DS.attr('string')
#with the help of collection, typ and subtyp i know exactly what kind of item i got (necklace, element, armbrace...)
  collection: DS.attr('string'),defaultValue: 'art_nou'
  typ: DS.attr('string'),defaultValue: 'element'
  subtyp: DS.attr('string'),defaultValue: 'misc'
#number of connections
  noc: DS.attr('string')
  price: DS.attr('string')
  img: DS.attr('string'),defaultValue: '/assets/'


  bigUrl:( ->
    url=@get('img')
    lastPart = url.split('/').pop()
    return '/assets/'+'LARGE_' + lastPart
  ).property('url')

 App.Item.reopenClass
  COLLECTIONS: ['art_nou', 'cleopatra', 'balance', 'pendant','rio_de_oro','simplicity', 'styx', 'misc']
  TYPES: ['mag','plug','tie']
  SUBTYPES:['d1','d1_2','plug_1','plug_2','plug_3','armband','halskette','element', 'ohrring'] 


  valid: (fields) ->
    fields.itemName
```

## tool template( this is the app, theres no routes )

```
section#tool


    // Kategorien
    #cat
        h1 Kollektionen
        ul
            li
                span.kategorie.alle click="showAll" []Alle
            li 

                category-control action="showCollection" kategorie="art_nou" name="Art Nouveau"

            li 

                category-control action="showCollection" kategorie="cleopatra" name="Cleopatra"
            li 

                category-control action="showCollection" kategorie="balance" name="Balance"
            li 

                category-control action="showCollection" kategorie="pendant" name="Pendant"
            li 

                category-control action="showCollection" kategorie="rio_de_oro" name="Rio de Oro"
            li 

                category-control action="showCollection" kategorie="simplicity" name="Simpliticy"
            li 

                category-control action="showCollection" kategorie="styx" name="Styx"



    //Katalog

    a class="runter chevron" click="scrollDown" 
        img src="assets/down.png"
    a class="rauf chevron" click="scrollUp" 
        img src="assets/up.png"
    div class={showCatalogue:kat:kat showCatalogue::kat-invisible }

        .container

            h2 
                |Unsere 
                =kollektionActive
                |  Kollektion 
            // muss variabel werden 

            span.kat-text Unsere Cleopatra Kollection zeichnet sich durch den individuellen Magnetverschluss aus.
            span.hr

            //will be components later          
            if halsketten
                h3 Unsere Halsketten
                div.row
                    each item in halsketten

                        draggable-item item=item
                            div.product
                                div.img 
                                    img src=item.img
                                div.itemName
                                    item.itemName


                div.clearfix
            if armbaender
                h3 Unsere Armbänder
                div.row
                    each item in armbaender

                        draggable-item item=item
                            div.product
                                div.img 
                                    img src=item.img
                                div.itemName
                                    item.itemName

                div.clearfix
            if ohrringe
                h3 Unsere Ohrringe
                div.row
                    each item in ohrringe

                        draggable-item item=item
                            div.product
                                div.img 
                                    img src=item.img
                                div.itemName
                                    item.itemName

                div.clearfix
            if elemente
                h3 Unsere Elemente
                div.row
                    each item in elemente

                        draggable-item item=item
                            div.product
                                div.img 
                                    img src=item.img
                                div.itemName
                                    item.itemName

                div.clearfix




    .ws
    bigUrl
    #drop
        draggable-dropzone action="addItem"

            each item in speicher
                img src=item.bigUrl




= outlet

footer
```

## tool controller

```
App.ToolController = Ember.ArrayController.extend


    # im drop bereich befindliche elemente
    speicher: Em.A([])



    # Katalog
    showDialog: false
    showCatalogue: false

    isActive: false

    kollektionActive: ''
    halsketten: Ember.computed.filterBy('controller','subtyp','halskette')
    armbaender: Ember.computed.filterBy('controller','subtyp','armband')
    ohrringe: Ember.computed.filterBy('controller','subtyp','ohrring')
    elemente: Ember.computed.filterBy('controller','subtyp','element')

    containerTop:"0"

    upVisible: (->

        containerTop=@get('containerTop')
        if containerTop>=0
            jQuery("a.rauf").delay(200).animate {opacity: "0"},500,'swing'

            return true

        else if containerTop<0

            jQuery("a.rauf").delay(200).animate {opacity: "1"},500,'swing'
            return false

        else 
            # alert("hmm")

        ).observes("containerTop")


    actions:
        addItem: (itemId) ->
            speicher = @get('speicher')
            # gedragtes item anhand von itemId im store finden
            item=@store.find "item", itemId
            speicher.pushObject item
            # console.log(speicher)


        resetTool: ->
            @set 'speicher', []

        showAll: ->
            kollektion=@get('model')
            @set 'controller', kollektion
            @set 'kollektionActive', 'gesamte'  
            @set 'showCatalogue', true

        showCollection: (collectionId,name) ->


            @set 'kollektionActive', name       
            kollektion=@get('model')
            filter=kollektion.filterBy('collection', collectionId)
            @set 'controller', filter
            @set 'showCatalogue', true
```

## draggable-item Component

```
App.DraggableItemComponent = Ember.Component.extend
    classNames        : [ 'draggable-item' ]
    attributeBindings : [ 'draggable' ]
    draggable         : 'true'

    dragStart: (event) ->
        event.dataTransfer.setData 'text/data', @get('item.id')
```

## draggable-dropzone Component

```
App.DraggableDropzoneComponent = Ember.Component.extend
    classNames        : [ 'draggable-dropzone' ]
    classNameBindings : [ 'dragClass' ]
    dragClass         : 'deactivated'



    dragLeave: (event) ->
        event.preventDefault()
        @set 'dragClass', 'deactivated'

    dragOver: (event) ->
        event.preventDefault()
        @set 'dragClass', 'activated'

    drop: (event) ->
        @set 'dragClass', 'deactivated'
        itemId = event.dataTransfer.getData('text/data')
        @sendAction "action" , itemId
```

## category-control

```
App.CategoryControlComponent = Ember.Component.extend
    # tagname:'span'
    classNames        : [ 'category' ]
    classNameBindings: ['active']
    active: false


    click: (event) ->
        @sendAction 'action', @get('kategorie'), @get('name')
        return
```

## JAVASCRIPT VERSION TRANSLATED BY WEBSERVICE js2.coffee

## item model

```
    App.Item = DS.Model.extend({
      itemName: DS.attr('string'),
      collection: DS.attr('string'),
 #with the help of collection, typ and subtyp i know exactly what kind of item i got (necklace, element, armbrace...)
      defaultValue: 'art_nou',
      typ: DS.attr('string'),
      defaultValue: 'element',
      subtyp: DS.attr('string'),
      defaultValue: 'misc',
#number of connections
      noc: DS.attr('string'),
      price: DS.attr('string'),
      img: DS.attr('string'),
      defaultValue: '/assets/',
      bigUrl: (function() {
        var lastPart, url;
        url = this.get('img');
        lastPart = url.split('/').pop();
        return '/assets/' + 'LARGE_' + lastPart;
      }).property('url')
    });

    App.Item.reopenClass({
      COLLECTIONS: ['art_nou', 'cleopatra', 'balance', 'pendant', 'rio_de_oro', 'simplicity', 'styx', 'misc'],
      TYPES: ['mag', 'plug', 'tie'],
      SUBTYPES: ['d1', 'd1_2', 'plug_1', 'plug_2', 'plug_3', 'armband', 'halskette', 'element', 'ohrring'],
      valid: function(fields) {
        return fields.itemName;
      }
    });
```

## tool controller

```
App.ToolController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  speicher: Em.A([]),
  showDialog: false,
  showCatalogue: false,
  isActive: false,
  kollektionActive: '',
  halsketten: Ember.computed.filterBy('controller', 'subtyp', 'halskette'),
  armbaender: Ember.computed.filterBy('controller', 'subtyp', 'armband'),
  ohrringe: Ember.computed.filterBy('controller', 'subtyp', 'ohrring'),
  elemente: Ember.computed.filterBy('controller', 'subtyp', 'element'),
  containerTop: "0",
  upVisible: (function() {
    var containerTop;
    containerTop = this.get('containerTop');
    if (containerTop >= 0) {
      jQuery("a.rauf").delay(200).animate({
        opacity: "0"
      }, 500, 'swing');
      return true;
    } else if (containerTop < 0) {
      jQuery("a.rauf").delay(200).animate({
        opacity: "1"
      }, 500, 'swing');
      return false;
    } else {

    }
  }).observes("containerTop"),
  actions: {
    addItem: function(itemId) {
      var item, speicher;
      speicher = this.get('speicher');
      item = this.store.find("item", itemId);
      return speicher.pushObject(item);
    },
    resetTool: function() {
      return this.set('speicher', []);
    },
    showAll: function() {
      var kollektion;
      kollektion = this.get('model');
      this.set('controller', kollektion);
      this.set('kollektionActive', 'gesamte');
      return this.set('showCatalogue', true);
    },
    showCollection: function(collectionId, name) {
      var filter, kollektion;
      this.set('kollektionActive', name);
      kollektion = this.get('model');
      filter = kollektion.filterBy('collection', collectionId);
      this.set('controller', filter);
      return this.set('showCatalogue', true);
    }
  }
});
```

## draggable-item component

```
App.DraggableItemComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
  classNames: ['draggable-item'],
  attributeBindings: ['draggable'],
  draggable: 'true',
  dragStart: function(event) {
    return event.dataTransfer.setData('text/data', this.get('item.id'));
  }
});
```

## draggable-dropzone component

```
App.DraggableDropzoneComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
  classNames: ['draggable-dropzone'],
  classNameBindings: ['dragClass'],
  dragClass: 'deactivated',
  dragLeave: function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    return this.set('dragClass', 'deactivated');
  },
  dragOver: function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    return this.set('dragClass', 'activated');
  },
  drop: function(event) {
    var itemId;
    this.set('dragClass', 'deactivated');
    itemId = event.dataTransfer.getData('text/data');
    return this.sendAction("action", itemId);
  }
});
```

## category-control component

```
App.CategoryControlComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
  classNames: ['category'],
  classNameBindings: ['active'],
  active: false,
  click: function(event) {
    this.sendAction('action', this.get('kategorie'), this.get('name'));
  }
});
```

Comment: Can you post some code of what you already have?

Comment: added the important code snippets

Comment: added javascript version translated by webservice www.js2.coffee - hope this is all valid